# Difference between last byte time and response time

Tags: java, byte, response

what is the difference between last byte time and response time in web applications.
I found

Last byte time: the time in seconds it took to download the final server response

Response time: the time it takes from when a user makes a request until they receive a complete response.

What is the difference.It seems both are same.
But practically both are giving different time values.what is the difference and how can I calculate the last byte time using java

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: "response time" can mean lots of things besides time to last byte for one request. How are you measuring it?

Comment: but last byte means final server response only according to above definitions.And how the last byte time can be measured since from giving a url in browser to until getting final response(final byte) or after connection establishment it is measured??

Answer (score 0):

Response time: It is the time elapsed between entering a url or clicking a link and getting the final byte of response from the server.

Last byte time: It is the time elapsed between sending a request(GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) to the server and getting the final byte of response from the server.

The response time will be always greater than the time to last byte because the browser will not send a request to the server as soon as you load a new URL. Before sending a request to the server, various events takes place. Some of them are: unloadEvent, domainLookUpEvent, connectionEvent and secureConnectionEvent. The easiest way to visualize this is by using the browser's performance API. 
Response time is obtained by `performance.timing.responseEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart`. And time to last byte is obtained by `performance.timing.responseEnd - performance.timing.requestStart`.

After a lot of research on **how can I calculate the last byte time using java**, I have found only one solution. If you need to calculate the last byte time for example.com, then you have to use selenium web driver and make a connection to example.com. Then by using JavaScriptExecutor you can get `performance.timing.responseEnd - performance.timing.requestStart` from the browser.

Comment: I don't understand this. can you clarify more?